# memory leak in keras while training a GAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a GAN using keras the problem is that I keep filling the RAM...
this is the code I used to train:

```
import gc
cont=0
while cont<20:
  cont+=1

  img_to_train_discr=image_generator(8)
  #it reurns a tuple(image, 0/1)
  discr.train_on_batch(img_to_train_discr[0], img_to_train_discr[1])
  img_to_train_gan=image_generator_for_gan(8)
  gan.train_on_batch(img_to_train_gan[0],img_to_train_gan[1])

found_objects = gc.get_objects()
```

both .fit and .train_on_batch show an increase of use memory through the epochs

I included gc.get_object because I I wanted to look into what element were not deleted

I itereted through the list found_objects and I found the probable cause of the problem.

it was saving the values...

but with .fit I saw that using .get_objects it saved some tensor such as:
the following was found while using.fit on gan

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 0.8039216   0.8039216   0.8039216 ]
  [ 0.77254903  0.77254903  0.77254903]
  [ 0.7647059   0.7647059   0.7647059 ]
  ...
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]]

 [[ 0.14509805  0.14509805  0.14509805]
  [-0.00392157 -0.00392157 -0.00392157]
  [-0.19215687 -0.19215687 -0.19215687]
  ...
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]]

 [[-0.37254903 -0.37254903 -0.37254903]
  [-0.34901962 -0.34901962 -0.34901962]
  [-0.29411766 -0.29411766 -0.29411766]
  ...
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]
  [ 0.9843137   0.9843137   0.9843137 ]]

 ...

 [[-0.99215686 -0.99215686 -0.99215686]
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]
  [-0.9843137  -0.9843137  -0.9843137 ]
  ...
  [-0.7019608  -0.7019608  -0.7019608 ]
  [-0.81960785 -0.81960785 -0.81960785]
  [-0.40392157 -0.40392157 -0.40392157]]

 [[-0.8352941  -0.8352941  -0.8352941 ]
  [-0.9843137  -0.9843137  -0.9843137 ]
  [-0.9529412  -0.9529412  -0.9529412 ]
  ...
  [-0.5921569  -0.5921569  -0.5921569 ]
  [-0.77254903 -0.77254903 -0.77254903]
  [-0.42745098 -0.42745098 -0.42745098]]

 [[-0.654902   -0.654902   -0.654902  ]
  [-0.90588236 -0.90588236 -0.90588236]
  [-0.8666667  -0.8666667  -0.8666667 ]
  ...
  [-0.77254903 -0.77254903 -0.77254903]
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.5529412  -0.5529412  -0.5529412 ]]]


[[[ 0.5764706   0.5764706   0.5764706 ]
  [ 0.5921569   0.5921569   0.5921569 ]
  [ 0.60784316  0.60784316  0.60784316]
  ...
  [ 0.5372549   0.5372549   0.5372549 ]
  [ 0.5058824   0.5058824   0.5058824 ]
  [ 0.49803922  0.49803922  0.49803922]]

 [[ 0.58431375  0.58431375  0.58431375]
  [ 0.6         0.6         0.6       ]
  [ 0.6156863   0.6156863   0.6156863 ]
  ...
  [ 0.5294118   0.5294118   0.5294118 ]
  [ 0.5058824   0.5058824   0.5058824 ]
  [ 0.49803922  0.49803922  0.49803922]]

 [[ 0.6         0.6         0.6       ]
  [ 0.60784316  0.60784316  0.60784316]
  [ 0.6156863   0.6156863   0.6156863 ]
  ...
  [ 0.5294118   0.5294118   0.5294118 ]
  [ 0.5294118   0.5294118   0.5294118 ]
  [ 0.5137255   0.5137255   0.5137255 ]]

 ...

 [[-0.8901961  -0.8901961  -0.8901961 ]
  [-0.8352941  -0.8352941  -0.8352941 ]
  [-0.6784314  -0.6784314  -0.6784314 ]
  ...
  [-0.99215686 -0.99215686 -0.99215686]
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]]

 [[-0.9137255  -0.9137255  -0.9137255 ]
  [-0.8901961  -0.8901961  -0.8901961 ]
  [-0.56078434 -0.56078434 -0.56078434]
  ...
  [-0.99215686 -0.99215686 -0.99215686]
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]]

 [[-0.77254903 -0.77254903 -0.77254903]
  [-0.75686276 -0.75686276 -0.75686276]
  [-0.7411765  -0.7411765  -0.7411765 ]
  ...
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]]]


[[[-0.94509804 -0.94509804 -0.94509804]
  [-0.88235295 -0.88235295 -0.88235295]
  [-0.8117647  -0.8117647  -0.8117647 ]
  ...
  [-0.9372549  -0.9372549  -0.9372549 ]
  [-0.8745098  -0.8745098  -0.8745098 ]
  [-0.9372549  -0.9372549  -0.9372549 ]]

 [[-0.9607843  -0.9607843  -0.9607843 ]
  [-0.94509804 -0.94509804 -0.94509804]
  [-0.7647059  -0.7647059  -0.7647059 ]
  ...
  [-0.9529412  -0.9529412  -0.9529412 ]
  [-0.8980392  -0.8980392  -0.8980392 ]
  [-0.9372549  -0.9372549  -0.9372549 ]]

 [[-0.9372549  -0.9372549  -0.9372549 ]
  [-0.9607843  -0.9607843  -0.9607843 ]
  [-0.7411765  -0.7411765  -0.7411765 ]
  ...
  [-0.9607843  -0.9607843  -0.9607843 ]
  [-0.92156863 -0.92156863 -0.92156863]
  [-0.9137255  -0.9137255  -0.9137255 ]]

 ...

 [[ 0.10588235  0.10588235  0.10588235]
  [ 0.10588235  0.10588235  0.10588235]
  [-0.01176471 -0.01176471 -0.01176471]
  ...
  [-0.19215687 -0.19215687 -0.19215687]
  [-0.23921569 -0.23921569 -0.23921569]
  [-0.19215687 -0.19215687 -0.19215687]]

 [[ 0.09019608  0.09019608  0.09019608]
  [ 0.11372549  0.11372549  0.11372549]
  [ 0.13725491  0.13725491  0.13725491]
  ...
  [ 0.01176471  0.01176471  0.01176471]
  [-0.05882353 -0.05882353 -0.05882353]
  [-0.07450981 -0.07450981 -0.07450981]]

 [[-0.08235294 -0.08235294 -0.08235294]
  [-0.15294118 -0.15294118 -0.15294118]
  [-0.09803922 -0.09803922 -0.09803922]
  ...
  [-0.15294118 -0.15294118 -0.15294118]
  [-0.01176471 -0.01176471 -0.01176471]
  [-0.03529412 -0.03529412 -0.03529412]]]


...


[[[-0.54509807 -0.54509807 -0.54509807]
  [-0.54509807 -0.54509807 -0.54509807]
  [-0.4117647  -0.4117647  -0.4117647 ]
  ...
  [-0.3647059  -0.3647059  -0.3647059 ]
  [ 0.37254903  0.37254903  0.37254903]
  [ 0.38039216  0.38039216  0.38039216]]

 [[-0.38039216 -0.38039216 -0.38039216]
  [-0.14509805 -0.14509805 -0.14509805]
  [-0.11372549 -0.11372549 -0.11372549]
  ...
  [-0.3882353  -0.3882353  -0.3882353 ]
  [-0.21568628 -0.21568628 -0.21568628]
  [ 0.16862746  0.16862746  0.16862746]]

 [[-0.06666667 -0.06666667 -0.06666667]
  [ 0.06666667  0.06666667  0.06666667]
  [-0.28627452 -0.28627452 -0.28627452]
  ...
  [ 0.38039216  0.38039216  0.38039216]
  [-0.44313726 -0.44313726 -0.44313726]
  [ 0.21568628  0.21568628  0.21568628]]

 ...

 [[ 0.21568628  0.21568628  0.21568628]
  [ 0.06666667  0.06666667  0.06666667]
  [-0.04313726 -0.04313726 -0.04313726]
  ...
  [-0.60784316 -0.60784316 -0.60784316]
  [-0.6156863  -0.6156863  -0.6156863 ]
  [-0.5686275  -0.5686275  -0.5686275 ]]

 [[ 0.31764707  0.31764707  0.31764707]
  [ 0.10588235  0.10588235  0.10588235]
  [-0.2784314  -0.2784314  -0.2784314 ]
  ...
  [-0.42745098 -0.42745098 -0.42745098]
  [-0.4509804  -0.4509804  -0.4509804 ]
  [-0.54509807 -0.54509807 -0.54509807]]

 [[ 0.12941177  0.12941177  0.12941177]
  [-0.08235294 -0.08235294 -0.08235294]
  [-0.04313726 -0.04313726 -0.04313726]
  ...
  [-0.79607844 -0.79607844 -0.79607844]
  [-0.5686275  -0.5686275  -0.5686275 ]
  [-0.2        -0.2        -0.2       ]]]


[[[-0.9529412  -0.9529412  -0.9529412 ]
  [-0.79607844 -0.79607844 -0.79607844]
  [-0.6156863  -0.6156863  -0.6156863 ]
  ...
  [-0.44313726 -0.44313726 -0.44313726]
  [-0.79607844 -0.79607844 -0.79607844]
  [-0.73333335 -0.73333335 -0.73333335]]

 [[-1.         -1.         -1.        ]
  [-0.90588236 -0.90588236 -0.90588236]
  [-0.6313726  -0.6313726  -0.6313726 ]
  ...
  [-0.3019608  -0.3019608  -0.3019608 ]
  [-0.8352941  -0.8352941  -0.8352941 ]
  [-0.7647059  -0.7647059  -0.7647059 ]]

 [[-1.         -1.         -1.        ]
  [-0.99215686 -0.99215686 -0.99215686]
  [-0.8039216  -0.8039216  -0.8039216 ]
  ...
  [-0.29411766 -0.29411766 -0.29411766]
  [-0.8117647  -0.8117647  -0.8117647 ]
  [-0.6862745  -0.6862745  -0.6862745 ]]

 ...

 [[-0.90588236 -0.90588236 -0.90588236]
  [-0.81960785 -0.81960785 -0.81960785]
  [-0.8117647  -0.8117647  -0.8117647 ]
  ...
  [-0.7647059  -0.7647059  -0.7647059 ]
  [-0.88235295 -0.88235295 -0.88235295]
  [-0.9137255  -0.9137255  -0.9137255 ]]

 [[-1.         -1.         -1.        ]
  [-0.9764706  -0.9764706  -0.9764706 ]
  [-0.9529412  -0.9529412  -0.9529412 ]
  ...
  [-0.8117647  -0.8117647  -0.8117647 ]
  [-0.8352941  -0.8352941  -0.8352941 ]
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]]

 [[-0.6862745  -0.6862745  -0.6862745 ]
  [-0.62352943 -0.62352943 -0.62352943]
  [-0.7411765  -0.7411765  -0.7411765 ]
  ...
  [-0.8117647  -0.8117647  -0.8117647 ]
  [-0.77254903 -0.77254903 -0.77254903]
  [-0.84313726 -0.84313726 -0.84313726]]]


[[[-0.69411767 -0.69411767 -0.69411767]
  [-0.6784314  -0.6784314  -0.6784314 ]
  [-0.6627451  -0.6627451  -0.6627451 ]
  ...
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]]

 [[-0.70980394 -0.70980394 -0.70980394]
  [-0.69411767 -0.69411767 -0.69411767]
  [-0.67058825 -0.67058825 -0.67058825]
  ...
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]]

 [[-0.7176471  -0.7176471  -0.7176471 ]
  [-0.69411767 -0.69411767 -0.69411767]
  [-0.6784314  -0.6784314  -0.6784314 ]
  ...
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]]

 ...

 [[-0.6313726  -0.6313726  -0.6313726 ]
  [-0.62352943 -0.62352943 -0.62352943]
  [-0.62352943 -0.62352943 -0.62352943]
  ...
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8666667  -0.8666667  -0.8666667 ]
  [-0.8745098  -0.8745098  -0.8745098 ]]

 [[-0.6156863  -0.6156863  -0.6156863 ]
  [-0.6156863  -0.6156863  -0.6156863 ]
  [-0.60784316 -0.60784316 -0.60784316]
  ...
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8666667  -0.8666667  -0.8666667 ]
  [-0.8745098  -0.8745098  -0.8745098 ]]

 [[-0.6156863  -0.6156863  -0.6156863 ]
  [-0.6156863  -0.6156863  -0.6156863 ]
  [-0.60784316 -0.60784316 -0.60784316]
  ...
  [-0.8509804  -0.8509804  -0.8509804 ]
  [-0.8666667  -0.8666667  -0.8666667 ]
  [-0.8666667  -0.8666667  -0.8666667 ]]]], shape=(16, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
692453
tf.Tensor(
[[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]], shape=(16, 1), dtype=float32)
```

and this is with training only discr

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(32, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[ 6.94478676e-03, -2.90532247e-03,  7.25293392e-03],
         [ 1.20958146e-02, -1.07863108e-02,  1.04020014e-02],
         [ 1.69709120e-02, -2.54366547e-02,  1.98477823e-02],
         ...,
         [-4.30019619e-03, -8.35454836e-03, -2.21172324e-03],
         [-4.14159754e-03, -1.14777510e-03, -1.21566129e-03],
         [ 1.36303401e-03,  6.04543777e-04, -1.35964795e-03]],

        [[ 2.50564199e-02, -6.16334006e-03,  1.92856099e-02],
         [ 3.54985110e-02, -1.79717932e-02,  2.98348404e-02],
         [ 2.62675621e-02, -1.90307051e-02,  2.65689045e-02],
         ...,
         [-1.57777814e-03, -6.14548009e-03,  5.52629726e-03],
         [ 3.56815499e-03, -6.90740068e-03, -7.03096506e-04],
         [ 9.26138775e-04, -1.85872870e-03,  3.02374363e-04]],

        [[ 2.74749734e-02, -1.49438502e-02,  2.80325040e-02],
         [ 5.10839783e-02, -1.75167620e-02,  2.70463582e-02],
         [ 3.75709981e-02, -2.34040022e-02,  2.50053518e-02],
         ...,
         [ 8.94943625e-03, -1.73010174e-02,  1.82440877e-02],
         [ 4.39342530e-03, -1.31681236e-02,  8.13111849e-03],
         [ 4.34517069e-03, -4.70215734e-03, -1.63908151e-03]],

        ...,

        [[ 6.95652468e-03, -3.63357402e-02,  4.07949500e-02],
         [ 4.13575359e-02, -4.91991192e-02,  3.21018584e-02],
         [ 4.74223010e-02, -7.47634992e-02,  2.35863868e-02],
         ...,
         [ 8.26232806e-02, -6.68739378e-02, -6.99709053e-04],
         [ 7.23878071e-02, -5.69532141e-02, -4.85424437e-02],
         [ 2.66422518e-02, -3.07060555e-02, -5.80600202e-02]],

        [[ 4.50124545e-03, -3.43432538e-02,  3.71103324e-02],
         [ 4.32977863e-02, -4.92802262e-02,  3.27052958e-02],
         [ 4.84924354e-02, -6.66223019e-02,  2.72663124e-02],
         ...,
         [ 7.71504492e-02, -7.50505701e-02,  2.73561082e-03],
         [ 8.03824887e-02, -6.13293871e-02, -3.52067165e-02],
         [ 2.08804533e-02, -2.86836233e-02, -5.02964184e-02]],

        [[-3.90984351e-03, -2.32026614e-02,  2.67444160e-02],
         [ 1.65205617e-02, -3.42688598e-02,  1.98613424e-02],
         [ 2.70076040e-02, -5.75522073e-02,  1.99076571e-02],
         ...,
         [ 5.09059504e-02, -5.42278290e-02,  1.30892009e-03],
         [ 6.47045597e-02, -3.80333811e-02, -2.18609013e-02],
         [ 3.41063663e-02, -1.05063524e-02, -3.07822768e-02]]],


       [[[ 1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  9.84313726e-01],
         [ 9.92156863e-01,  9.76470590e-01,  9.76470590e-01],
         ...,
         [ 9.76470590e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.84313726e-01],
         [ 9.92156863e-01,  9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00]],

        [[ 9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.84313726e-01],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01],
         [ 9.92156863e-01,  9.92156863e-01,  9.92156863e-01],
         ...,
         [ 9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00]],

        [[ 9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 9.29411769e-01,  9.45098042e-01,  9.45098042e-01],
         [ 9.68627453e-01,  9.84313726e-01,  9.84313726e-01],
         ...,
         [ 9.76470590e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.84313726e-01],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00]],

        ...,

        [[ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
         ...,
         [ 9.68627453e-01,  9.84313726e-01,  9.84313726e-01],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]],

        [[ 9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 9.76470590e-01,  9.92156863e-01,  9.92156863e-01],
         [ 9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
         ...,
         [ 9.76470590e-01,  9.92156863e-01,  9.92156863e-01],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00]],

        [[ 9.68627453e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 9.60784316e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01],
         [ 9.84313726e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
         ...,
         [ 9.60784316e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00],
         [ 1.00000000e+00,  9.92156863e-01,  1.00000000e+00]]],


       [[[-9.76470590e-01, -1.00000000e+00, -1.05882354e-01],
         [-9.76470590e-01, -1.00000000e+00, -9.01960805e-02],
         [-9.60784316e-01, -9.92156863e-01, -5.88235296e-02],
         ...,
         [-7.45098069e-02, -4.74509805e-01, -2.07843140e-01],
         [ 1.05882354e-01, -3.56862754e-01, -1.37254909e-01],
         [ 2.54901975e-01, -2.54901975e-01, -5.88235296e-02]],

        [[-9.76470590e-01, -1.00000000e+00, -7.45098069e-02],
         [-9.84313726e-01, -1.00000000e+00, -6.66666701e-02],
         [-9.84313726e-01, -9.92156863e-01, -5.09803928e-02],
         ...,
         [-1.05882354e-01, -4.98039216e-01, -2.31372550e-01],
         [ 7.45098069e-02, -3.80392164e-01, -1.60784319e-01],
         [ 2.07843140e-01, -2.78431386e-01, -9.01960805e-02]],

        [[-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -6.66666701e-02],
         [-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -5.88235296e-02],
         [-1.00000000e+00, -9.92156863e-01, -3.52941193e-02],
         ...,
         [-2.00000003e-01, -5.52941203e-01, -2.94117659e-01],
         [ 3.92156886e-03, -4.19607848e-01, -1.92156866e-01],
         [ 1.52941182e-01, -3.01960796e-01, -1.05882354e-01]],

        ...,

        [[-1.00000000e+00, -5.52941203e-01, -4.66666669e-01],
         [-8.27450991e-01, -2.31372550e-01, -1.84313729e-01],
         [-8.50980401e-01, -8.23529437e-02, -1.29411772e-01],
         ...,
         [-8.50980401e-01, -7.25490212e-01, -4.98039216e-01],
         [-7.17647076e-01, -5.52941203e-01, -3.33333343e-01],
         [-1.00000000e+00, -8.27450991e-01, -6.07843161e-01]],

        [[-1.00000000e+00, -5.13725519e-01, -4.11764711e-01],
         [-8.35294127e-01, -2.47058824e-01, -1.84313729e-01],
         [-9.05882359e-01, -1.68627456e-01, -2.07843140e-01],
         ...,
         [-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -7.56862760e-01],
         [-8.43137264e-01, -6.70588255e-01, -4.50980395e-01],
         [-8.03921580e-01, -5.60784340e-01, -3.64705890e-01]],

        [[-1.00000000e+00, -5.29411793e-01, -4.27450985e-01],
         [-9.21568632e-01, -3.09803933e-01, -2.54901975e-01],
         [-9.52941179e-01, -2.47058824e-01, -2.86274523e-01],
         ...,
         [-1.00000000e+00, -9.68627453e-01, -6.94117665e-01],
         [-1.00000000e+00, -9.29411769e-01, -7.09803939e-01],
         [-9.29411769e-01, -6.62745118e-01, -4.74509805e-01]]],


       ...,


       [[[-1.05062379e-02, -1.98420249e-02,  1.05182398e-02],
         [-3.95061001e-02, -2.57582217e-02,  1.40950643e-02],
         [-2.30170805e-02, -2.37071346e-02, -4.61883796e-03],
         ...,
         [-2.45160554e-02, -9.46635101e-03, -6.07647886e-03],
         [-3.07144760e-03,  2.74786772e-03, -6.80177147e-03],
         [ 5.86585980e-03,  2.40193726e-03,  3.39358579e-04]],

        [[ 3.22993868e-03, -1.12008387e-02,  3.77045646e-02],
         [-9.38666333e-03, -3.21227647e-02,  2.93544959e-02],
         [-1.12627428e-02, -1.63189527e-02,  4.86864848e-03],
         ...,
         [-2.86157615e-02, -8.67746118e-03, -9.11490759e-04],
         [-1.50391981e-02, -5.08068223e-03, -9.21393745e-03],
         [ 6.01480622e-03, -8.89253570e-04,  5.72130177e-03]],

        [[ 2.37215031e-02,  1.73019955e-03,  3.52669656e-02],
         [ 2.20054798e-02,  3.41841788e-03,  2.78164726e-02],
         [ 2.26932168e-02,  2.25211773e-02, -7.15107657e-03],
         ...,
         [-9.92084946e-03, -7.83571042e-03,  5.36113139e-03],
         [-3.63909150e-03, -2.15192046e-02,  1.81183417e-03],
         [ 9.87425633e-03, -1.63576566e-02,  9.68800485e-03]],

        ...,

        [[ 9.26712807e-03, -3.34203020e-02,  3.94128822e-02],
         [ 4.19912934e-02, -4.55853753e-02,  3.37843001e-02],
         [ 4.08300571e-02, -6.73395097e-02,  2.53548753e-02],
         ...,
         [ 8.61984789e-02, -7.02210069e-02, -4.39706072e-03],
         [ 6.94279298e-02, -5.77976443e-02, -4.75803465e-02],
         [ 2.45513227e-02, -3.38402092e-02, -5.75863346e-02]],

        [[ 6.77845301e-03, -3.54054347e-02,  3.67174037e-02],
         [ 4.35878709e-02, -4.94687334e-02,  3.45391147e-02],
         [ 4.71395329e-02, -7.13703632e-02,  2.63372287e-02],
         ...,
         [ 8.29759017e-02, -7.53538832e-02,  1.60004944e-04],
         [ 8.16767067e-02, -6.00483567e-02, -3.75034474e-02],
         [ 1.97965931e-02, -3.06959040e-02, -5.22228405e-02]],

        [[-2.94655445e-03, -1.86929759e-02,  2.33796220e-02],
         [ 1.59196425e-02, -3.28605361e-02,  1.64255649e-02],
         [ 2.53022909e-02, -4.75350842e-02,  1.15010655e-02],
         ...,
         [ 5.44254147e-02, -5.55038191e-02, -1.54604076e-03],
         [ 6.76389188e-02, -3.61473970e-02, -2.54233293e-02],
         [ 3.42441052e-02, -9.63416602e-03, -3.30452174e-02]]],


       [[[ 2.54648067e-02, -1.19450670e-02,  3.30261998e-02],
         [ 4.23403606e-02, -4.13185284e-02,  3.81897315e-02],
         [ 4.00563851e-02, -6.79321066e-02,  4.91125546e-02],
         ...,
         [ 4.02044021e-02, -5.85264936e-02,  5.48310988e-02],
         [ 2.70577967e-02, -4.31953967e-02,  3.57147492e-02],
         [ 6.32039411e-03, -2.48100758e-02, -7.03164516e-03]],

        [[ 3.70886363e-02, -2.01733522e-02,  6.05700798e-02],
         [ 7.77267516e-02, -5.13126105e-02,  6.01464622e-02],
         [ 8.56612101e-02, -8.36809576e-02,  7.61673301e-02],
         ...,
         [ 8.45839083e-02, -4.61416878e-02,  6.01974353e-02],
         [ 5.06575927e-02, -2.32018791e-02,  2.58594193e-02],
         [ 1.53260147e-02, -1.76541489e-02, -2.82484554e-02]],

        [[ 2.97332872e-02, -2.54155342e-02,  7.12449625e-02],
         [ 9.13045332e-02, -6.03631884e-02,  7.43178874e-02],
         [ 9.26255956e-02, -9.32793990e-02,  7.50018954e-02],
         ...,
         [ 1.09376043e-01, -5.31297959e-02,  4.94755656e-02],
         [ 7.15198442e-02, -3.02166399e-02,  1.11023467e-02],
         [ 1.66346878e-02, -3.10882907e-02, -3.92567255e-02]],

        ...,

        [[ 1.50115313e-02, -5.51447719e-02,  6.36151060e-02],
         [ 7.06077367e-02, -7.18016624e-02,  5.44297658e-02],
         [ 6.90411255e-02, -1.04166776e-01,  3.75158228e-02],
         ...,
         [ 9.69356075e-02, -7.91200697e-02, -8.72911653e-04],
         [ 8.63938630e-02, -6.63577765e-02, -5.73743023e-02],
         [ 3.16326991e-02, -3.84405665e-02, -6.70467839e-02]],

        [[ 1.09571004e-02, -5.76814674e-02,  5.85661493e-02],
         [ 7.11029768e-02, -7.61615336e-02,  5.38719222e-02],
         [ 7.62823075e-02, -1.09212406e-01,  3.92470434e-02],
         ...,
         [ 9.16330442e-02, -8.96104947e-02,  4.14223457e-03],
         [ 9.69443470e-02, -7.11727366e-02, -4.28451747e-02],
         [ 2.50954758e-02, -3.50896828e-02, -6.06248528e-02]],

        [[-4.41576634e-03, -3.03974133e-02,  3.74333374e-02],
         [ 2.65656877e-02, -5.15482500e-02,  2.55387109e-02],
         [ 4.18888927e-02, -7.42964670e-02,  1.65963285e-02],
         ...,
         [ 5.96264340e-02, -6.26873225e-02,  4.92919178e-04],
         [ 7.69837126e-02, -4.49479558e-02, -2.73446627e-02],
         [ 4.12025116e-02, -1.18885487e-02, -3.75647955e-02]]],


       [[[ 2.21067071e-02, -1.11255171e-02,  2.79338863e-02],
         [ 3.44552584e-02, -3.55523229e-02,  2.96750609e-02],
         [ 2.81813368e-02, -5.43026328e-02,  3.58022302e-02],
         ...,
         [ 1.64286569e-02, -2.56849099e-02,  1.86677016e-02],
         [ 8.29113834e-03, -2.09341552e-02,  1.19914617e-02],
         [ 9.81146120e-04, -9.67385620e-03, -4.16056439e-03]],

        [[ 3.28787938e-02, -1.61599461e-02,  5.14922813e-02],
         [ 6.91715330e-02, -4.29286025e-02,  4.98180874e-02],
         [ 6.63172528e-02, -6.69079795e-02,  5.72132170e-02],
         ...,
         [ 3.04000657e-02, -2.18527243e-02,  1.85649637e-02],
         [ 1.70135573e-02, -1.09965997e-02,  8.97353794e-03],
         [ 4.53805597e-03, -5.36913285e-03, -1.20095760e-02]],

        [[ 2.78143492e-02, -1.96416155e-02,  6.09582961e-02],
         [ 7.77031854e-02, -4.75680716e-02,  6.22547753e-02],
         [ 7.32004791e-02, -7.40943998e-02,  5.90784885e-02],
         ...,
         [ 3.82998213e-02, -2.72356309e-02,  1.36684459e-02],
         [ 2.71414351e-02, -1.12283370e-02,  6.70646504e-03],
         [ 9.00707394e-03, -1.34321274e-02, -1.47624528e-02]],

        ...,

        [[ 1.46386446e-02, -5.67819588e-02,  6.60154596e-02],
         [ 7.21150413e-02, -7.36338943e-02,  5.58988042e-02],
         [ 7.18126446e-02, -1.06876150e-01,  3.95014845e-02],
         ...,
         [ 8.86510685e-02, -7.16847479e-02, -5.57619939e-03],
         [ 7.46077448e-02, -6.13973439e-02, -5.14714606e-02],
         [ 2.69034542e-02, -3.52577232e-02, -6.09280579e-02]],

        [[ 1.07796416e-02, -5.97048812e-02,  6.08111545e-02],
         [ 7.26786703e-02, -7.89055601e-02,  5.58755845e-02],
         [ 7.88586289e-02, -1.12460330e-01,  4.03497480e-02],
         ...,
         [ 8.51700082e-02, -8.18825141e-02,  6.48484449e-04],
         [ 8.65846053e-02, -6.51570857e-02, -3.90671641e-02],
         [ 2.17908174e-02, -3.32889743e-02, -5.32799624e-02]],

        [[-5.24961576e-03, -3.11195180e-02,  3.85811515e-02],
         [ 2.61344314e-02, -5.40103428e-02,  2.65447777e-02],
         [ 4.28958423e-02, -7.67953098e-02,  1.69624444e-02],
         ...,
         [ 5.64608611e-02, -5.83225712e-02, -9.28662426e-04],
         [ 7.05104247e-02, -3.99363190e-02, -2.56322399e-02],
         [ 3.73998210e-02, -1.12367878e-02, -3.46269831e-02]]]],
      dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(32,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])>]
```

the same thing happened if instead of using train_on_batch I used .fit. But .fit is much faster because I am using a generator.

moreover I am confident that there is a memory leak inside the fit/train_on_batch as the inputs are numpy arrays, not tensor

It appears that the memory does not increase linearly but with spikes.

I am using a pretrained resnet_v2.ResNet50V2 in discr

PS I am not 100% sure of what is happening with train_on_batch as while printing the list of elements of gc.get_object it encounters some difficulties and the ram starts filling until it chrashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue where a memory leak appears in TF 2.x keras when calling the network repeatedly in a loop.

I have come across several suggestions online:

- Call `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` and possibly `gc.collect()` every now and then in the loop (via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366819/how-to-make-sure-the-training-phase-wont-be-facing-an-oom))
- Wrap your `train_on_batch` or model call in a function with the `@tf.function` decorator (this worked for me)

Comment: Thank you!
I downgraded to tensorflow 1.x and it seems to work correctly

I tried `gc.collect()` but it did not help and I think ` tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`  is useful when I have multiple models not when looping

` @tf.function`  as you said probably could have solved but it produced some strange errors.
So I went with the option of downgrading to tensorflow 1.x